# interrupt handler does not get called when the interrupt is issued

Tags: c, linux

I'm writing a driver for a device running on ARM.

Here's the code for the probe() and the interrupt_handler():

```
static irqreturn_t interrupt_handler(int irq, void *dev_id){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "MY_IRQ: Interrupt handler executed!\n");
    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

static int mydevice_probe (struct platform_device *pdev) {
    printk("-----------------------------------------PROBE CALLED \n");
    r = platform_get_resource(pdev, IORESOURCE_MEM, 0);
    if(r == NULL) {
        printk("platform_get_resource failed\n");
        return -ENODEV;
    }
    irq = platform_get_irq(pdev,0);
    if (irq < 0) {
        printk("platform_get_irq failed\n");
        return -ENODEV;
    }

    ret = request_irq(irq, interrupt_handler, IRQF_SHARED, pdev->name, &dev_num);
    ret = misc_register(&mydevice_miscdevice);
    return 0;
}
```

The `request_irq` successfully returns 0 and the IRQ #17 is assigned to the driver.
The problem is, when the interrupt is issued, the interrupt handler doesn't get executed.

Any idea? What did I miss?

Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, an issue of good practice - the calls to `request_irq` and `misc_register` should be protected by `if` clauses that `printk` and `return -EIO` on failure.

Perhaps you are not enabling the interrupt. You should probably add code to clear and then enable the interrupt after the call to `request_irq`.

Comment: I just figured it out a sec ago.
Yeah it was because I haven't enabled the interrupt correctly.
Now it works fine.
Thank you.